# How to extract the licensetype and corresponding id using JMeter and pass it to next HTTP API request?

Tags: jmeter

From response need to extract the licensetype and corresponding id (based on licensetype, id changes - ex: licensetype 'full', there can be 20 ids associated, licensetype 'half' can be 100 ids associated). This extracted info needs to be passed to next 'POST' request by passing licensetype and ids as shown in the screenshot.

How to extract this kind of combination using JMeter and pass it to next HTTP API request? I can extract each one  like licensetype and ids separately using RegEx or JSON path extractor however I need to specify the combination in the next request. Please guide.

[image: licensetype and id in response]

[image: next post request]

Answer (score 1):

General recommendation: use [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/) to construct the JSON Payload programmatically using [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class. Previously extracted IDs can be accessed using `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance.

References:

- [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)